# What is the faster way of counting? Using count query in the database or counting retrieved rows programmatically?

Tags: database, count

I was wondering what would be a faster way as far as counting rows is concerned from a database? Is count query in DB (server) going to be faster than some sort of count in a program (client). 
I think the things that are to be considered are

- Size of the database
- Programing language use
- Are the rows that are to be counted required by the client?

Any suggestions?

Comment: problematically? do you mean programmatically?

Comment: It will depend on the storage engine and the actual query - check COUNT in InnoDb vs MyISAM.

Comment: @Merca My question is more on a general term, let us not talk about specific DBs or language
Wug programmatically :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just the counting by itself cannot be made any faster than executing it in a compiled language like C++, C# or Java. Counting through a stream of rows is *nothing*.

Unfortunately, copying the rows from the server to the client is enormously more expensive that counting them. So you are always better off letting the server count them.

I literally cannot think of a scenario in which one should count on the client (if the only thing required is the count, not the rows themselves).

#### If the rows are required on the client:

1. If all rows are required: Count on the client
2. If only a single page is required: Count on the server! There might be hundreds or thousands of pages and you don't want to download all of them. The RDBMS can often optimize counting because no column data is required to count.

Comment: I agree with what you say @usr, but what if the rows are required in the client side? In that case would you still stick to counting in server as a better way then client? 
What do you think is the additional load on the server or is the load because of count a factor at all?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the requirement is, I would rather do it at the data base level and counting the rows at client would require to transfer the rows to the client. Some question to be looked at are

  Is the over head of passing rows to the client needed?

  Frequency of database access by application

  How big are the rows that is to be sent(Size of rows)

Considering all these, I would go with counting at the DB level in general, but again as I said in the beginning. It depends on the scenario where we would like to implement it.